# How to make YoloV5 detect by screen grab?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolov5

I am using the following in order to grab screenshots from an open application in realtime. How can I run detect.py that only detect input from my grab screen? Thanks.

My grab screen

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

bounding_box = {'top': 340, 'left': 800, 'width': 350, 'height': 400}

sct = mss()


while True:
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    scr_img = np.array(sct_img)

    #cv2.imshow('screen', scr_img) # display screen in box
    cv.imshow('Testing', scr_img)

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

YoloV5 detect.py

For now it only detect images instead of my Realtime grab screen

```
# PyTorch Hub
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

# Images
dir = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/'
imgs = [dir + f for f in ('zidane.jpg', 'bus.jpg')]  # batch of images

# Inference
results = model(imgs)
results.print()  # or .show(), .save()
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jut pass the screen grab to the model:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

# PyTorch Hub
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

bounding_box = {'top': 340, 'left': 800, 'width': 350, 'height': 400}

sct = mss()


while True:
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    scr_img = np.array(sct_img)

    #cv2.imshow('screen', scr_img) # display screen in box
    scr_img = model(scr_img)
    cv.imshow('Testing', scr_img)

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for ur respond, i tried but the code return me `line 26, in <module>
    cv.imshow('Testing', scr_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'`

Comment: oh, try with `scr_img.show()` maybe the model is returning an object, not just the postporoces picture.

Comment: yes, when I use `scr_img.show()`, it returning me as image. Does it mean i need to save the image everytime and read from it  ?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you can access the image some other way you can use cv2.imshow(), something similar to this `img = scr_img.show()`. If this doesn't work try to find the source from the `.show()` method and see what variable are they printing.

Comment: The image is still showing up because of  `.show()`. I tried `img = scr_img.show()
    cv.imshow('Testing', img)`

Comment: I think i found it. Try `cv.imshow('Testing', scr_img.imgs)` . Here is the "result" class, there are many methods line 348. [link](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/2317f86ca4ee140ed6a50fc0cc9857383f755ecd/models/common.py#L399)